# 1998 Honda Civic LX coolant spillage after running AC

Tags: engine, ac, coolant, air, radiator-overflow

I ran my car yesterday for about 4 hours and there were no issues. Upon going out to my car this morning, I notice a leak of some sort coming from underneath my car. So I touched it and sniffed, sure enough it was coolant. I began a quick overview of the engine; all fluids at normal levels, including the coolant. So I searched to attempt to locate the source of the leak. Didnt find it, though the stain on the ground started near the firewall. If anyone has ANY opinions and/or expert advice I'd appreciate it.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! You're positive it was coolant and not A/C condensation? Where was the puddle in regard to the vehicle itself?

Comment: I’m with Paulster on the a/c condensate here. Where are you located?  ( humidity and ambient temperature there?) in high humidity areas it wouldn’t surprise me to see at least a cup of water condensate in an hour of running.

Comment: I live in Maryland and it was about the location of the starter, but just a bit back towards the firewall. It was probably about a cup. It was coolant and not water.